# Finding the trace of $(I + \Sigma^{-1} AA^T)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, trace

I need to efficiently compute the trace of 
$$
B = (I + \Sigma^{-1} AA^T)^{-1}
$$
where $\Sigma$ is diagonal and all its elements strictly greater than zero. $A$ is $-1$ on the diagonal and $1$ right below it, thus $AA^T$ will be tridiagonal. Some example for $A$:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\end{matrix}\right]
$$

I have been scratching my head for a while now. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391128/trace-of-an-inverse-matrix) made me believe that trying to diagonalize $B$. Some attempts to do so algebraically failed.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

If it can be shown that this is not possible without explicitly writing down $B$, this would also help me. (It would stop me try to find a solution :)

Comment: $\Sigma$ is diagonal? Any more information?

Comment: I forgot: all its elements are greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

One idea: note that if the entries of $\Sigma$ are sufficiently large, then setting $M=  \Sigma^{-1}AA^T$we can write
$$
(I + M)^{-1} =
I - M + M^2 - M^3 + \cdots
$$