# Computing $\operatorname{Tr} \bigl( \bigl( (A+I )^{-1} \bigr)^2\bigr)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, trace

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix  such that $\operatorname{Tr}(A)\le n$. I want a lower bound on the following quantity 
$$\operatorname{Tr} \bigl( \bigl( (A+I )^{-1} \bigr)^2\bigr)$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

My intuition tells me it should be

$$
\operatorname{Tr} \bigl( \bigl( (A+I )^{-1} \bigr)^2\bigr) \ge 1/4
$$

However, I'm not sure how to show it. Also my intuition might be wrong?

Comment: Could be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391128/trace-of-an-inverse-matrix

Comment: The expression is invariant under conjugation, and $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Squirtle thank. But the square inside is hard to deal with

Comment: @anomaly  Is that a suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: @Boby: Well, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By spectral theorem, there is invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$
P^{-1}(I+A)P=\pmatrix{1+\mu_1 \\ & \ddots & \\ & & 1+\mu_n}
$$
where $\mu_i$ is eigenvalue of $A$ and $\mu_i\geqslant0$. So 
$$
(I+A)^{-1}=P\pmatrix{\dfrac1{1+\mu_1} \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \dfrac1{1+\mu_n}}P^{-1}
$$
And
$$
((I+A)^{-1})^2=P\pmatrix{\dfrac1{(1+\mu_1)^2} \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \dfrac1{(1+\mu_n)^2}}P^{-1}
$$
So
$$
Tr(((I+A)^{-1})^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac1{(1+\mu_i)^2}\leqslant n
$$
Then by $\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i\leqslant n$, we have $\mu_i\leqslant n$ for all $i$. So a lower bound is
$$
Tr(((I+A)^{-1})^2)\geqslant\frac{n}{(1+n)^2}
$$

Comment: @Boby, you should convince yourself (google or prove it yourself) that adding the identity to a matrix will shift the eigenspectrum in the manner of this proof (on line one).

Comment: @hermes Sorry, but it is not clear to me how does this help to find the lower bound. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: @hermes I mean this calculation only implies an obvious lower bound $n\cdot \frac{1}{(1+n)^2}$. But this is very far from the conjectured one and definitely not optimal.

Comment: @L.G. Not sure but maybe we can use concavity of $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ to show that $\sum _{i=1} \frac{1}{(1+\mu_i)^2} \ge  \frac{1}{(1+\sum _{i=1}\mu_i)^2}  =\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: The conjecture may not be true.I mean we can get a lower bound but it may not be $1/4$. The lower bound can be obtained by Lagrangian multiplier.

Comment: @hermes Naively I would say that the minimum is realized when all the eigenvalues are equal to $1$, so that the optimal lower bound is $n/4$. But to show this rigorously one indeed needs to carefully analyze the optimization problem.

Comment: @Boby $1/(1+x^2)$ is convex, but it does not matter. You can certainly minimize your function $\sum 1/(1+\mu_i)^2$ subject to $\mu_i\ge 0$ and $\sum\mu_i=n$ (easy to see that equality should be active at minimum) by e.g. KKT. I guess that all $\mu_i=1$ is the optimal choice.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is real symmetric, there exists a matrix $P$ such that

$$PAP^{-1} = D =\verb/diag/(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)$$
is diagonal with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. This leads to

$$P (I_n+A)^{-2}P^{-1} = (I_n + PAP^{-1})^{-2} = \verb/diag/\left(\frac{1}{(1+\lambda_1)^2},\ldots,\frac{1}{(1+\lambda_n)^2}\right)\\
\implies \verb/Tr/((I_n + A)^{-2}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1+\lambda_i)^2}$$

Consider the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$. It is easy to check
for $x \in (0,\infty)$,
$$g(x) > 0,
\quad
g'(x) = -\frac{2}{(1+x)^3} < 0
\quad\text{ and }\quad
g''(x) = \frac{6}{(1+x)^4} > 0$$
This means $g(x)$ is a positive, monotonic decreasing and convex function over $(0,\infty)$.
By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), 
we obtain following lower bound:

$$\verb/Tr/((I_n + A)^{-2})
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} g(\lambda_i) 
\underbrace{\ge}_{\text{Jensen}}
n g\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)
\underbrace{\ge}_{g\text{ decreasing}}  
n g(1) = \frac{n}{4}$$

Since $\verb/Tr/(I_n) \le n$ and $\verb/Tr/((I_n + I_n)^{-2}) = \frac{n}{4}$, above lower bound $\frac{n}{4}$ is achievable and hence the optimal one.

As a consequence,
your intution $\verb/Tr/((I_n + A)^{-1}) \ge \frac14$ is true (but far from the optimal).

Comment: +1 Yet $\frac14\ge\frac{n}{(1+n)^2}$, so the OP's bound is at least better than the one given in the other answer ;D