# Matrix trace inequality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck on this problem. I have no idea how to proceed, so any help would be welcome.

Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite matrix $n\times n$ prove that :
$$\operatorname{trace}(A) * \operatorname{trace}(A^{-1}) \ge n^2$$

Comment: Hint: What is the relationship between trace and eigenvalues? What can you say about eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix?

Comment: They are positive ?

Comment: That answers the second question. What about the first?

Comment: Sum of eigenvalues is same as trace

Comment: Exactly. Finally, what are the eigenvalues of the inverse? You can put those three facts together to get what you need.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391128/trace-of-an-inverse-matrix i have found this, ok I am now up to something. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $D$ be a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $0<\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$. Then we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(D)\operatorname{tr}(D^{-1}) =&\ \left(\lambda_1+\cdots +\lambda_n \right)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\lambda_n} \right)\geq\ n^2
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from the [AM-HM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means#Inequalities_among_means).