Prove that $\min_{\pi \in \mathbb{R}^n} \operatorname{tr}\left[(X^T \operatorname{diag}(\pi)\: X)^{-1}\right]$ is convex opt problem
Prove that the following is convex optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
\min_{\pi \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \quad \operatorname{tr}\left[(X^T \operatorname{diag}(\pi)\: X)^{-1}\right] \\
\text{s. t.} & \quad \pi \geq 0, \\
& \quad \mathbf{1}^T \pi = 1
\end{align*}
$X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and $\pi \in \mathbb{R}^n$
Hint: Treat the trace as a sum of $p$ variables, where each of the $p$ variables is set to some expression involving $X$ and $\pi$. Transform the equation defining each of these elements into an SDP constraint, using the Schur lemma:
So I wrote the whole matrix $X^T \operatorname{diag}(\pi) X$ as a sum of variables but what I can I do with the inverse. Any hints?

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

it's the rendering that I have an issue with

@JoséCarlosSantos can you help put the minimization function in the title ?

@user2614870 I adjusted the math expression in the title to render properly by removing the ampersand and also an eyesore \quad. Please check and adjust.

@BenSteffan, thanks, it looks good

@vassilisP. I think your best chances is following the DCP Rule Set and show it is a convex function.

The only other idea I have is based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391128. The inner matrix is indeed PSD by the constraints. So it might be doable to show its eigen values as a function of $\boldsymbol{\pi}$.

@Royi I will take a look soon and give some feedback
